# Will I ever actually make "al mitzvat tzitzit" on a daily basis if I don a tallit gadol?

Tags: blessing, tzitzis, tallit-gadol, nusach-sefard

I wear a tallit katan at almost all times and I do, in fact, sleep in it. I spoke to a rabbi about whether I would actually ever make "*al mitzvat tzitzit*" and it seemed that the answer was no. Kitzur also informs me that one doesn't make the blessing when putting on the tallit katan after a shower, as far as I know. So, if I'm donning a tallit gadol every morning for Shacharit, will I ever actually make "al mitzvat tzitzit" on a daily basis?

Comment: I know that the halacha is that one who dons a talit gadol for shacharit every morning does not make a b'racha on donning his talit katan. (If I have a chance to look up the sources later, I will post an answer if no one else has.) Personally, I have not made the b'racha *al mitzvat tzitzit* since I became *bar mitzva* and starting wearing a talit gadol.

Comment: For those wondering, I am yekke (of German descent), not *sefardi*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not on a daily basis, but maybe on a weekly basis if you put a different *tallit katan* on for Shabbos. Also, summer's coming up and if you go to the beach or the pool you'll almost invariably have your *tallit katan* off long enough for there to be *hesech hadaas*, so when you put it back on you'll make a *bracha* on it.

I think some people might argue that in both these cases you can have intention to cover these situations when you make your *bracha* in the morning, therefore would not make a *bracha*, but personally I never have the presence of mind to think that far ahead.

Comment: Note that there are also many sefeqot brought down in the Mishnah Berurah (Siman 8) as regards a *tallit qatan*. And, since *berakhot lo me'akvot*, one would almost never make this berakhah.

Answer (score 3):

at least sefaradim don't make this beracha, and i have yet to find a sidur with it.
just because we say lehitatef everyday we also have intention on the talit catan, this is also part of the leshem ihud as rabenu iosef haim suggests