# Tallit Katan and Tallit brachot

Tags: halacha, blessing, tallit-gadol, men-male, tallit-katan

Why is that when you wake up you put on a Tallit Katan and then you go to shul and put on a Tallit Gadol?  How is it that you can say two different brachot? If it is in fact, that each peice of clothing gets the the chance for a new bracha, are there any other mitzvot, aside from food, where we recite a bracha each and every time we do the SAME action?  Of those allowed are there any we commonly do multiple time as we do with the Tallit?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7718/will-i-ever-actually-make-al-mitzvat-tzitzit-on-a-daily-basis-if-i-don-a-talli

Comment: Related near-duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11302

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do married men stop saying a bracha on their *tallit katan*?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11302/do-married-men-stop-saying-a-bracha-on-their-tallit-katan)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The custom among (as far as I know all) *Ashk'nazim* (and maybe among others also?) is that someone who dons a *talis katan* in the morning intending to don a *talis gadol* later (for prayers) does not say a *b'racha* on the former. However, I have no citation for this: I'm not seeing it in the *Mishna B'rura*, and certain parts of *Shulchan Aruch Orach Chayim* 8 seem to directly contradict it (cf. [Double AA's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12811)).

*Update:* As Shalom mentions in a comment on this answer, [*MB* 8:24](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&pgnum=27) cites with approval the practice I am familiar with.

Comment: see: http://revach.net/ask/article.php?id=1813

Comment: But I am very skeptical about his answer.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11302/do-married-men-stop-saying-a-bracha-on-their-tallit-katan Mishnah Brurah 8:24

Comment: @msh210 All this means that really you should make separate brachot as I mentioned in my answer, only due to a number of sfeikot involved in a tallit katan's eligibility for tzitzit, we avoid making any bracha on it when possible. This chashash is not something discussed in the shulchan aruch and likely is not something that applies to many of today's talitot ketanot which are designed to be much "more kosher" than the ones that the Mishna Brurah discusses in OC 16 middle of sk 4 sv Umah shenohagim. Thus for most of us we should return to saying brachot at the proper times.

Comment: @DoubleAA, very likely, but that's a consult-your-rabbi issue. Here, I can do no more than quote the masters (in this case the _MB_).

Comment: @msh210 Of course CYLOR! I'm just defending my leaving this out of my answer below, especially when the question did not specifically reference it. BTW see also MB 16:1 and his quote from the Darkei Moshe.

Comment: To Double AA, please clarify: why are there sfeikot involved in a tallit katan's eligibility for tzitzit? What are the sfeikot? I'm putting together an short article on tzitzit and would greatly appreciate your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Each individual four-cornered piece of clothing is independently obligated in tzitzit and gets its own bracha. See Shulchan Aruch OC 8:12,13

Comment: I think the question becomes, how is that?  Are their other mitzvot we do, aside from food, that allow us to do the SAME mitzvah multiple times each with its own bracha?  Do we commonly do them? (I will amend the question accordingly.

Comment: @morahhochman I'm not sure what you mean by doing a mitzva multiple times. We have multiple mezuzot in our houses, and one can slaughter many different cows.

Comment: @DoubleAA: sure, but you say one berachah to cover all of the mezuzos you're putting up one after the other, and similarly for slaughtering animals.

Comment: @Alex Same for tzitzit if you put them on immediately one after another. See OC 8:12